# Overriding NSLayoutConstraint in an inherited class

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

There are two classes in my code, one is `NameCell`, which contains a simple UILabel with text. The second one is `NameValueCell`, which inherits from that class, but adds also the property `UIView *valueView`.

One layout constraint needs to be altered. I'm looking for a way to override:

`H:|[nameView]|` - `nameView` should occupy full width in `NameCell`

with

`H:|[nameView][valueView(==nameView)]|` - `nameView` to `valueView` width ratio should be 1:1 in `NameValueCell`

What is the best practice out there for overriding NSLayoutConstraint? I have to stick to inheritance in my code because my application requires many different UITableViewCell specializations.

NameCell.h:

```
@interface NameCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *nameView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;

@end
```

NameValueCell.h:

```
@interface NameValueCell : NameCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *valueView;

@end
```

NameCell.m:

```
@implementation NameCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        UIView *nameView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.nameView = nameView;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.nameView];

        UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.nameLabel = nameLabel;
        [self.nameView addSubview:self.nameLabel];

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameView, nameLabel);
        NSArray *constraints;

        // The constraint that should be overridden
        constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[nameView]|"
                                                              options: 0
                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                views:views];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];        
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

NameValueCell.m:

```
@implementation NameValueCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSString *reuseID = reuseIdentifier;

        UIView *valueView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.valueView = valueView;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.valueView];

        NSDictionary *views = @{
                                @"nameView": self.nameView,
                                @"nameLabel": self.nameLabel,
                                @"valueView": self.valueView
                                };
        NSArray *constraints;

        // The overriding constraint
        constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[nameView][valueView(==nameView)]|"
                                                                       options: 0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];        
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The subclass wants to *augment* the superclass behavior, for example, by adding additional subviews; but it also wants to *override* the superclass when it comes to creating constraints.  To do both, the best approach is to factor out the view creating and the constraint creating code, then in the subclass, control whether we're augmenting or overriding by calling `super` selectively.

First, factor out...

```
// in NameCell.m initWithStyle
// super initWithStyle..., if (self) { ...
[self addCustomSubviews];
[self addCustomConstraints];
```

In `NameCell`, these new methods should be implemented exactly as you have them inline in the question, but in the subclass: (1) don't implement init at all, allowing the superclass init to call the factored code, and (2) override the factored code as follows...

```
// NameValueCell.m
- (void)addCustomSubviews {
    // augmenting super here, so call super...
    [super addCustomSubviews];

    // add the value view
    UIView *valueView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    // and so on
}

- (void)addCustomConstraints {
    // overriding super here, so don't call super, just add constraints
    NSDictionary *views = @{
       // and so in
}
```

In a less fussy but less clear alternative, you could just leave your inits as they are, but in the subclass init, remove the constraints that were just created in the super...

```
// in NameValueCell.m, in the initWithStyle method, before creating constraints
[self removeConstraints:self.constraints];  // then ...
NSDictionary *views = @{ // and so on...
```

I wouldn't call this alternative a best (or even good) practice, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

First: don't *add* constraints; *activate* them. It's far simpler and less error-prone.

Okay, then. Just keep a reference to the constraints that might need replacing in an NSArray instance variable:

```
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[nameView]|"
                                                      options: 0
                                                      metrics:nil
                                                        views:views];
self.removeableConstraints = constraints; // an instance property
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints: constraints];
```

Now all the subclass has to do is *deactivate* `self.removeableConstraints` and activate its substitute constraints.

```
[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints: self.removeableConstraints];
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[nameView][valueView(==nameView)]|"
                                                      options: 0
                                                      metrics:nil
                                                        views:views];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints: constraints];
```

That is the general pattern for swapping out constraints, and there is no reason that the class/subclass relationship here shouldn't use it.

Comment: Also, I think the visual format language is for the chop, as it is proving increasingly inadequate; I recommend that you switch to the newer anchor-based notation.